# Issue with Eventviewer log

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, event-viewer

Using below:

```
$pattern = 'Unable to create Load Balance Manager object!'
$events = Get-WinEvent -ea SilentlyContinue `
-ProviderName "Hyperion Financial Data Quality Management - Task Manager Service"|
Where-Object { $_.TimeCreated -gt [datetime]::now.AddMinutes(-15) -and $_.Message -match $pattern }
$events   >> G:\Sysadmin\FDMmonitor\Error.txt
```

I'm getting Error.txt as below:

```
TimeCreated         ProviderName                         Id Message            
-----------         ------------                         -- -------            
1/24/2014 11:41:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:41:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:41:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:40:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:39:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:39:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:39:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:39:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:38:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:37:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:37:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:37:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:36:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
1/24/2014 11:36:... Hyperion Financi...                   0 Unable to create...
```

I'm not getting, why `TimeCreated, ProviderName and Message` are not coming with full text ?

What I need to change in my code to get some more text for these columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the results as you see them on the screen without anything shortened, you might try changing your code like this:

```
 $events = Get-WinEvent -ea SilentlyContinue `
-ProviderName "Hyperion Financial Data Quality Management - Task Manager Service"|
Where-Object { $_.TimeCreated -gt [datetime]::now.AddMinutes(-15) -and $_.Message -match $pattern }
$events |format-table -AutoSize |out-file -append -encoding Ascii G:\Sysadmin\FDMmonitor\Error.txt -width 300
```

Comment: To distill that, the significant part of this answer is: pipe through `| Format-Table -AutoSize` before piping the output to the file. Note, however, that if the data is too long, columns that don't fit will be dropped from the end. Also, note that `| Out-File -Append` is the same as `>>` (the latter is shorthand for the former)

Comment: Correct and that's why I started my answer by qualifying that. I would not use the the output format OP is asking, but that's a choice, not the question.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you are not in the USA?  I ask because I am in the UK and I find that the Get-WinEvent log benefits from this addition, or preamble:

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = `
New-Object "System.Globalization.CultureInfo" "en-US"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the export-csv class. 
This way you can open the table in Excel.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try the `-ExpandProperty` option. See [this Technet link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/6ad142a6-e270-478c-b02c-65ae2d3fa7db/preventing-cutoff-getting-full-output-from-powershell?forum=ITCG)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the append operator, try this:

```
... | Out-File G:\Sysadmin\FDMmonitor\Error.txt -Width 200
```

You can make the output width as wide as you need it with the -Width parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it still sends ellipsis even if you have a massive `out-file -width` further down the pipeline. In those cases you can use the `Format-Table` with the `-Wrap` and `-AutoSize` parameters to prevent truncation prior to output.

```
Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
```